# RAML Unknown facet 'types'

Tags: anypoint-studio, raml

I am receiving an issue with a datatype .raml file that I am attempting to create. For some reason, it is stating that I am **'Specifying unknown facet 'types'** as an error.

What is the proper way to go about defining an object in RAML?

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType
types:
  Account:
    type: object
    displayName: Account
    description: Salesforce Account Object
    properties:
      id:
        type: string
        description: Id of the Salesforce Account
      ns_id:
        type: string
        description: Id of NetSuite Customer
      name:
        type: string
        description: Name of Salesforce Account
      phone:
        type: string
        description: Phone Number of Salesforce Account
      website:
        type: string
        description: Website of the Salesforce Account
      owner:
        type: string # This probably needs to be of type Owner
        description: Owner of Account
      active_cmrr:
        type: number
        description: Active CMRR of Account
      billing_address:
        type: string
        description: Billing Address of Account
      subscription_start_date:
        type: date-only
        description: Salesforce Account Subscription Start Date
      subscription_end_date: 
        type: date-only
        description: Salesforce Account Subscription End Date
      #Sometype of Opportunity list
      #opportunities:
      #  type: Opportunity[]
      #  description: List of Account Opportunities
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently using a so called RAML fragment which focuses on a single definition only. In your case a single type definition.

You start defining multiple type definitions usually using `types` either in a root RAML file (indicated with `#%RAML 1.0`) or in a library (indicated with `#%RAML 1.0 Library`). So depending on what you try to achieve you either modify your data type fragment to only contain the definition of the `Account` type or you change `#%RAML 1.0 DataType` to `#%RAML 1.0 Library` so you can package multiple type definition into one; or you use both for max reusability.

Let me show you how to use both:

***account.raml***

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType

type: object
displayName: Account
description: Salesforce Account Object
properties:
  id:
    type: string
    description: Id of the Salesforce Account
  ns_id:
    type: string
    description: Id of NetSuite Customer
  name:
    type: string
    description: Name of Salesforce Account
  phone:
    type: string
    description: Phone Number of Salesforce Account
  website:
    type: string
    description: Website of the Salesforce Account
  owner:
    type: string # This probably needs to be of type Owner
    description: Owner of Account
  active_cmrr:
    type: number
    description: Active CMRR of Account
  billing_address:
    type: string
    description: Billing Address of Account
  subscription_start_date:
    type: date-only
    description: Salesforce Account Subscription Start Date
  subscription_end_date:
    type: date-only
    description: Salesforce Account Subscription End Date
  #Sometype of Opportunity list
  #opportunities:
  #  type: Opportunity[]
  #  description: List of Account Opportunities
```

***types.raml***

```
#%RAML 1.0 Library

types:
  Account: !include account.raml
```

In other type definition you could then use the library to reference to the account type. For example:

***bank.raml***

```
#%RAML 1.0 DataType

uses:
  types: types.raml

type: object
properties:
  branch: string
  accounts:
    type: array
    items: types.Account
```

Hope that helps you! Let me know if you have any further questions.